# VS2012 methods organizing by drag-and-drop

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I work in VS2012 and would like to organize the order of members in a class by drag-and-drop, like I can in Eclipse.

However, the members outline in a right-top of the screen and also in a class view or in solution explorer do not give such an option.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Solution Explorer and the members drop down always sort alphabetically. You can't change this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Code Maid](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/76293c4d-8c16-4f4a-aee6-21f83a571496) is a free Visual Studio extension that adds a `digging` window tool.

This will answer to your needs, I believe.

[image]

This tool also allow you to reorder code elements with drag & drop directly within this window.